# vertical accordion overflow and scroll issue

Tags: css, image, scroll, overflow, hidden

I am using a vertical accordion from CoDrops. The problem I am having is that whenever I add more image slices than the number of visibleSlices I have listed in the javascript, then they are not on overflow:hidden (as listed in my css.) The extra images slices are placed below the last image slice and the page simply gets longer (because the overflow hidden is not working, i assume.) Additionally, there are supposed to be arrows that appear that the user can click on to scroll to the next (hidden) image slice. While these do appear on the screen, they do not scroll if clicked on or if you are looking at the last image in the set of image slices and click on the next arrow (not knowing it is the last image) then all the images and text go away leaving a blank white page that does not correct itself unless you refresh the page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

My javascript for the accordion looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#va-accordion').vaccordion({
                accordianW: $(window).width(1000),
                accordianH: $(window).height(450),
                expandedHeight: 450,
                visibleSlices: 8,
                animOpacity: .2,
            });
        });
        </script>
```

My css for the vertical accordion looks like this: (only showing 1 image slice out of many)

```
.va-container{
position:relative;
top:50px;
margin:0px auto 0 auto;
}
.va-wrapper{
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
background:#FFF;
}
.va-slice{
cursor:pointer;
position:absolute;
width:100%;
left:100px;
overflow:hidden;
}
.va-slice-1{
background:#FFF url(../images/testa.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
```

(here's my scroll button css:)

```
.va-nav span{
width:40px;
height:25px;
background:transparent url(../images/prev.png) no-repeat center center;
position:absolute;
top:-35px;
left:50%;
margin-left:-20px;
text-indent:-9000px;
opacity:0.5;
cursor:pointer;
display:none;
z-index:100;
}
.va-nav span.va-nav-next{
background-image:url(../images/next.png);
top:auto;
bottom:-35px;
}
.va-nav span:hover{
opacity:1.0;
}
```

CoDrop's javascript looks like this: (they don't use the options listed on their demo page, but their accordion does what it is supposed to do.)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#va-accordion').vaccordion();
        });
    </script>
```

CoDrop's css looks like this:

```
.va-container{
position:relative;
margin:40px auto 0 auto;
}
.va-wrapper{
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
background:#000;
}
.va-slice{
cursor:pointer;
position:absolute;
width:100%;
left:0px;
overflow:hidden;
}
.va-slice-1{
background:#000 url(../images/1.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
```

CoDrop's scroll button css:

```
.va-nav span{
width:40px;
height:25px;
background:transparent url(../images/prev.png) no-repeat center center;
position:absolute;
top:-35px;
left:50%;
margin-left:-20px;
text-indent:-9000px;
opacity:0.7;
cursor:pointer;
display:none;
z-index:100;
}
.va-nav span.va-nav-next{
background-image:url(../images/next.png);
top:auto;
bottom:-35px;
}
.va-nav span:hover{
opacity:1.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you have overflow: hidden; in .va-container {}  ?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I just tried that and it solves the problem of the extra image slices showing up. However, it also causes the scroll (prev/next) buttons to disappear and so I can't ever see or scroll to any more image slices that the ones I have made visible in the javascript for the vertical accordion...

Comment: Also, I just noticed that if I do not have overflow:hidden; in the .va-container, then the image slices still override the javascript and they all show up on the page, despite the fact that I put visibleSlices as 8 (there are more than 8 image slices total, I just want the rest to be hidden and only 8 showing).